# Update a una Columna SQL con inormacion de Excel

Tags: php, sql, excel

La verdad no estoy muy seguro de como atacar este problema.
Tengo una tabla ***usuarios*** :

```
id nombre dato
1  juan   1a
2  pedro  2b 
3  paco   3c
```

Un documento en Excel de nombre ***documento***:

```
   A
1  01a
2  02b
3  03c
```

Mi intencion es que atraves de un boton PHP (u otra manera) pueda Actualizar la columna ***dato*** de la tabla ***usuarios***, la verdad es que me encuentro algo perdido en este caso

Comment: ¿Y como pretendes pasar lo que hay en el Excel al SQL? Porque puede ser desde una interfaz que hagas en PHP como lo mencionas en tus tags o que lo hagas directamente desde el SQL, pero esto depende de tu necesidad, es decir si tienes una aplicación y el usuario va a estar realizando esta actividad continuamente pues si tendrias que crear una interfaz y si digamos que es algo que solo vas a hacer una sola vez para llenar esa información puedes intentarlo desde el SQL.

Comment: es para acragar mensual mente una informacion , y si es para pasarlo atraves de PHP

Comment: En ese caso si es necesario que realices una interfaz en PHP para que el usuario suba el documento de Excel y tu por medio del PHP lo leas y hagas las actualizaciones correspondientes.